# Parse Information from an Address

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I currently have an address which might look something like this.

```
5235 Georgia Street Apt 8
436 Oregon Avenue Apartment # 5
... etc
```

I have a table called Address_length with 2 address columns (address_1 and address_2)
address_2 is supposed to contain apartment information.

What would be the easiest way to Update address_2 with a string of information from address_1.
If I see the word Apt or Apartment, I would like to include that word and everything right of it in that column.

So with the above example(s) the output would look like this.

```
address_1              address_2
5235 Georgia Street    Apt 8
436 Oregon Avenue      Apartment # 5
```

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is a difficult one. I would star creating a table with the different strings that will represent an apartment, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ApartmentsStrings
VALUES (N'apt'),(N'apartment');
```

Then I would do the following:

```
SELECT  A.[Address] OriginalAddress,
        CASE WHEN B.Position IS NOT NULL 
        THEN LEFT(A.[Address],B.Position-1) 
        ELSE A.[Address] END Address_1,
        CASE WHEN B.Position IS NOT NULL 
        THEN SUBSTRING(A.[Address],B.Position,LEN(A.[Address])-B.Position+1) END Address_2
FROM Address A
OUTER APPLY(SELECT PATINDEX('%'+String+'%',A.[Address]) Position
            FROM ApartmentsStrings
            WHERE PATINDEX('%'+String+'%',A.[Address]) > 0) B
```

The results:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║         OriginalAddress         ║      Address_1       ║   Address_2   ║
╠═════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 5235 Georgia Street Apt 8       ║ 5235 Georgia Street  ║ Apt 8         ║
║ 436 Oregon Avenue Apartment # 5 ║ 436 Oregon Avenue    ║ Apartment # 5 ║
╚═════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

You will have duplicates when a string that defines an apartment is contained in another one (ie: `apart` and `apartment`). There is also a great possibilty of false positives, meaning that you can have addresses that include `apt` but it didn't meant apartment.

[**Here is an**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8e0e/1) sqlfiddle for you to try.